# ddrescue to recover files

Tags: command-line, partitioning, ddrescue

I know nothing about `ddrescue`. I just ran the command

```
Sudo ddrescue -d r 3 source destination logfile
```

It's running right now, but I don't If I am doing it right.

```
Errsize is 1Tb
Errors:2
Rescued:2818KB
```

Why is error size so large and rescued size so less?

I have enclosed the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Kindly tell me if I am doing it right, or shall I abort it?

Comment: Hopefully this is first pass, and it will go back over and look at the data in a much finer way afterwards. Can you post the contents of the "logfile"?

Comment: My laptop screen went blank after sometime, just automatically, it's not turning ON, keyboard backlit is ON,  EVEN screen's backlight is ON.I have waited for 1hour but still not turning ON. what if I force shutdown my laptop? Will I be able to resume ddrescue?

Comment: yes, ddrescue should pick up from the "logfile" if you type the command the same way, in the same location

Comment: Yeah ,it resumed.Thanks a lot.

Comment: But tell me ,on resuming you said to use same command.But wait, I want to change the command like: I want to add -n option for no scrap.I Don't know what it means but I read somewhere that it will make operation faster. And I want to change bs value just to speed up operation.I only have vidoes not much important.few MBs of data lost I can manage.Tell me I fI can change the command to speed up?

Comment: mostly it picks reasonable defaults, and should work quickly, it really depends on the physical damage to the disk.  the scrape phase happens at the end, so it shouldn't make much difference.  I usually specify "retry passes = 1" `-r 1` and specify "verbose" `-v` but beyond that I usually leave it as is

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell for sure whether I misused ddrescue or it is buggy or malware. I ran it under Ubuntu 20.04 to clone an old 1 Tb HDD into a same size SSD. After some time the graphics screen went off and a flood of yellow characters came into view announcing thousands of disk write errors. Ctrl-alt, escape key, Ctrl-c... could not stop the race. The only way out was turning power off.
Results:
-Bootable System HDD was rendered non-bootable. It took booting from a USB key and using fsck manually to fix it.
-Destination SSD volume lost its bootable partition. Fixed with Gparted.
-Source volume remained allright!
Using old good dd did the job.
So, BEWARE!